# Why do I have XML-Related Apache classes throwing exceptions?

Tags: java, eclipse, xmlbeans

It seems like whenever I try to use XML-related classes in my Dynamic Web Projects in Eclipse and I try to run a class with a main method just for testing, I'm getting errors like `AbstractMethodError` and `NoSuchMethodError`.

It seems like some kind of classpath issue since I had identical versions of these projects running fine on my machine before it was formatted.

An example that tries to use XMLBeans:

> Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: com.ecw.adapterservice.schema.p2p.impl.ReferralRequestTypeImpl.generatedSetterHelperImpl(Lorg/apache/xmlbeans/XmlObject;Ljavax/xml/namespace/QName;IS)Lorg/apache/xmlbeans/XmlObject;

An example that tries to use a simple DOM parser:

> Exception in thread "main" java.lang.AbstractMethodError: org.apache.xerces.dom.ElementImpl.setTextContent(Ljava/lang/String;)V

One interesting thing I noticed is that when I try to launch my executable class from within my project, Eclipse pops up a window that searches my entire project for 'main types'. I don't think I've ever seen it do this before and I suspect it may be related to the problems I'm having.

Again, please note that identical copies of the source/libs for these projects used to be able to run the same individual classes without issue.

Does anyone have any insight into this issue? This is driving me nuts.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like both errors were the result of jar conflicts. Duly noted.

Answer (score 1):

JAR file incompability. 
To resolve it, use "Xerces2 Java" from here:
http://xerces.apache.org/mirrors.cgi